# Counting the number of zero's in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, counting

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Rate': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]})
df.head()  



          Score              Rate
    0       1                1.0
    1       2                0.0
    2       3                0.0
    3       4                0.5
    4       5                0.5
```

I am trying to count the number of Rates equal to 0 and show the corresponding score

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

you can use loc:

```
df.loc[df.Rate.eq(0)]

Score   Rate
1   2   0.0
2   3   0.0
```

Or if you just need to see Score:

```
df.loc[df.Rate.eq(0)].Score
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then get counts and sum of colun `Score`:

```
df = df.loc[df['Rate'].eq(0), 'Score'].agg(['sum','size'])
print (df)
sum     5
size    2
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(df[df['Rate']==0]['Score'])
```